# Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express error loading Silverlight

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#, templates, silverlight

**What's going on?**:  After selecting Silverlight Navigation with Accent Color from Online Templates in Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2010 Express, I am receiving the following error message.

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight, Version=10.0.0.0, ...'.  For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.

**What have I done?**: I've gone to the page that allows you to [customize project templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx), but I still don't understand what needs to be done.  To be more specific, I don't understand if this requires some coding process behind setting up a custom template (if so, I have viewed it and it doesn't make sense).

**Question**: Is there a simple "click here and select this check box" (Ex. Click on Tools, click on Templates...) that isn't mentioned in the documentation?  If not, what more can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These threads contain some suggestions for what can be done :

[Creating new MVC 3 project Error: this template attempted to load component assembly](http://forums.asp.net/t/1794308.aspx/1?Creating+new+MVC+3+project+Error+this+template+attempted+to+load+component+assembly+)
[Error creating a new project of a Custom Feature Extension](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/thread/1fc85850-e615-496c-afed-7676f53adc33/)

Evidently there can be more than one reason for such problems, and I don't have your environment.

In extremity, you might try to repair or reinstall all the software involved in a logical order, starting with Visual Studio and going on to extensions.

Comment: I repaired, uninstalled and reinstalled the program... no luck.  I also tried disabling and enabling the extensions... still no luck.  I will try to create a blank Silverlight document at school and open it up on my laptop tomorrow.

Comment: The computers at my school don't have Silverlight and I can't modify any programs (I don't have administrative access).

Comment: Have you installed a beta version of Silverlight or VS2010 ? Have you fully patched Windows Update including optional items?

Comment: Windows Update is fully patched, includes optional items, and I just installed Silverlight 5.  On the other hand, the version of Visual Studio I am using is for "evaluation purpose" only (I have about two weeks left).

Comment: My question was because beta versions are hard to install over. You could verify your setup against [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1368139/165358) for prerequisite software for Silverlight development (taking instead the 2010 versions), in case your problem is of some missed-out assemblies, so the Silverlight assembly can't load. Event Viewer might also contain some more info about the error.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I just finished up classes.  I reinstalled everything in the proper order and I continue to get the same error message.  This Event Viewer thing might have some answers but I have no idea how to use it.  I have referred to several forums and articles on how to use it, but I'm still clueless (mostly with navigating and deciphering messages that pertain to Visual Studio).

Comment: This [event viewer article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/better-troubleshooting-capabilities-with-windows-7-event-viewer/3226) might help. Create a custom view or filter on all errors and warning, make the error happen, then view recent messages.

Comment: Oh boy... this still doesn't make much sense to me.  I just wanted to use Silverlight to get a better handle on its functionality and create a website.  I can still do so through some simple HTML, CSS, and jQuery.  Your help is very much appreciated. +1

Comment: Another try you could make is to install using [Visual Studio 2010 Express All-in-One ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express-iso). This might work if the normal Internet installation is for some reason broken in your case.